# Box API to get file name sorted by Name

Tags: box-api, box

I couldn't find any documentation to sort box folder contents by Name.
Do we have any API available for the same.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you cannot request the items in a folder to be returned in a specific order, but you will be provided with information regarding the order they have been returned in.

Please take a look at the answer from a Box team member on a similar question: [Ordering of get folder items API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547380/ordering-of-get-folder-items-api-call)

Answer (score 0):

Box API now supports sort and direction attribute. For more details

https://developer.box.com/en/reference/get-folders-id-items/#param-sort